# How to find values which were found before inside multi array

Tags: php, arrays, find, unique

i do have currently following problem. I have to check if the array contains the exact same values and if they were found before.

int(3) wasn´t found before so it is 0,
int(8) wasn´t found before so it is 0,
int(5) wasn´t found before so it is 0,
int(8) was found before so it is 1,
int(3) and int(8) was not found together so it is 0, and so on.

I already tried it with array_unique but that didn´t work as i wanted

For example:

```
array(7) {
  [2] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(3)
  }
  [3] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(8)
  }
  [4] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(5)
  }
  [5] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(8)
  }
  [6] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(3)
    [1] => int(8)
  }
  [7] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(2)
    [1] => int(5)
  }
  [8] => array(2) {
    [0] => int(3)
    [1] => int(8)
  }
}
```

it must look something like this

```
array(7) {
  [2] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(0)
  }
  [3] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(0)
  }
  [4] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(0)
  }
  [5] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(1)
  }
  [6] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(0)
  }
  [7] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(0)
  }
  [8] => array(1) {
    [0] => int(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `array_map()` and `serialize()`:

```
<?php

$data = [
    2 => [
        3,
    ],
    3 => [
        8,
    ],
    4 => [
        5,
    ],
    5 => [
        8,
    ],
    6 => [
        3,
        8,
    ],
    7 => [
        2,
        5,
    ],
    8 => [
        3,
        8,
    ],
];

$occurrences = [];

$mapped = array_map(function (array $values) use (&$occurrences) {
    // create serialized representation of the values
    // which we can use as an index 
    $index = serialize($values);

    // haven't seen these values before
    if (!array_key_exists($index, $occurrences)) {
        $occurrences[$index] = 1;

        return 0;
    }

    // increase our counter
    $occurrences[$index]++;

    return $occurrences[$index] - 1;
}, $data);

var_dump($mapped);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/oWBcS

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$new_array = array();
$indicator = array();
$current_array = array(
    "2" => array(3),
    "3" => array(8),
    "4" => array(5),
    "5" => array(8),
    "6" => array(3,8),
    "7" => array(2,5),
    "8" => array(3,8),
    );


foreach($current_array as $key => $value){
    if(!in_array($value, $new_array, true)){
        $new_array[$key] = $value;
        $indicator[$key] = false;
    } else {
        $indicator[$key] = true;
    }
}

var_dump($indicator);
```

Comment: This assigns `false` if the values have not been used before, and `true`, if they have been used before - but you were asking for integers, indicating the number of times they have been used before, is that right?